# Repeat static cell

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a fairly complex view in a table view controller. Up until now the content has been static in that the data on the view is always the same layout however now there is a need to add in a dynamic data source.

All my research shows that I can not have repeating content inside a static table view and I need to subclass the current cells. This will be a huge task so I thought I would post here to ask if someone knows a way to have repeating static cell?

Thanks

Comment: You can have repeating content in a static table view; you just have to copy & paste the cell as many times as needed. That's not ideal, but it's certainly legal.

Comment: I did think of that thanks but because there is an unknown number of returned data this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question and comments correctly, you need to be able to render an unknown number of one of your cells. To my knowledge this cannot be done. Static table views are just that - static.

It might be possible to somehow dynamically change the static list of cells in the table view, but I've not seen that done. It's also likely to be less easy to maintain and harder for other developers to pick up.

I know it will involve some work but the best answer is to convert to a dynamic table view.